# How to export data to csv sequentially from multiple data frames in a sequential order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have multiple dataframes like below.

DF1:

[image]

DF2

[image]

DF3

[image]

I want to store them to a file like below.So the data should be in sequential order from each dataframe. Can any one help me to find a way to store in the below format in a file.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) instead post the data as text so contributors can copy into their system

Comment: You could write each dataframe to a seperate csv file and then combine them

Comment: Thank You @Nathan, How to combine them sequential order from CSV any idea ?

Comment: @Debasis I'm sure there's better ways, but you could write a function that takes a list of csv files and copies all of them line by line into a final file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)**:

```
df = DF1.append(DF2).append(DF3)
```

Then write it to a file using **[`df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)** file:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

OR to an excel file using **[`df.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):**

```
df.to_excel('test.xls')
```

**OR** (as per @anky 's comment): use **[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)**

```
df_list = [DF1,DF2,DF3] ## create a list with your dataframes
df = pd.concat(df_list)

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: I dont think append will work over here, as if you see it picks individual records from each dataframes and then paste in sequential order.Its like the first record from DF1 and then the first record from DF2 and the first record from DF3 and similar way it continues.

Comment: No, that is not how `append` works. Please try it once. It will append all dataframes sequentially.